# How to reference websites in the Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I have  used the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{book}    
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\bibitem{lecture11}http://math.mit.edu/classes/18.745/Notes/Lecture_11_Notes.pdf

\bibitem{Wiki1}https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system#/media/File:Root_system_A1xA1.svg

\bibitem{Wiki2}https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system#/media/File:Root_system_A2.svg

\bibitem{Wiki3}https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system#/media/File:Root_system_B2.svg

\bibitem{Wiki4}https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system#/media/File:Root_system_G2.svg

\end{thebibliography}
```

Unfortunately, it did not compile, but when i put fake websites like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-system/media/File:Root-system-G2.svg, it works. So if someone can fix this error, i am very grateful and thankful.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you load the `xurl` package and encase each URL string in a `\url{...}` directive. Observe that URL strings may (and often do) contain characters such as `_` and `#`, which have special meaning in TeX. Encasing the URL strings in `\url` directives is the way to go.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{book}    
\usepackage{xurl}
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\bibitem{lecture11} \url{http://math.mit.edu/classes/18.745/Notes/Lecture_11_Notes.pdf}

\bibitem{Wiki1} \url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system#/media/File:Root_system_A1xA1.svg}

\bibitem{Wiki2} \url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system#/media/File:Root_system_A2.svg}

\bibitem{Wiki3} \url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system#/media/File:Root_system_B2.svg}

\bibitem{Wiki4} \url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system#/media/File:Root_system_G2.svg}

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, to address the OP's follow-up request:

> I want to change colours of the websites. How to do it?

I will assume that you meant to say that you wish to change the color of the URL strings. (You don't need LaTeX to change the color of a website, do you?) I suggest you add the following lines of code to the preamble, *after* loading the `xurl` package:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=red} % or blue, or orange, or whichever color you prefer
```

With these instructions, URL strings will be rendered in whatever color you set via the `urlcolor` option.

Comment: Thank you very much Mico.

Comment: But I want to change colours of the websites. How to do it?

Comment: @AdamHammam - But why “but”?  Have you tried loading the `xcolor` and `hyperref` packages, the latter with the option `colorlinks`? Then, run `hypersetup{urlcolor=<yourdesiredcolorhere>}`.

Comment: Mico i didn't download xcolor and hyperref packages. Can you explain to me how to use colorlinks and  hypersetup{urlcolor=<yourdesiredcolorhere>}. I am very grateful i don't know how to thank you @Mico.

Comment: @AdamHammam - Please see the addendum I posted.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @AdamHammam - If you believe that my answer fully solved the issue you were looking to resolve, please feel free to click on the "accept" checkmark symbol to the top left of the answer. ;-)

Comment: I am sorry i didn't find the "accept" checkmark.